# Add day of week to a time in Python strptime

Tags: python, datetime, csv, strptime

I have two columns in a csv file, one of which has the time in the format hh:mm:ss and the other has the day of week with 1 equal to Monday and 7 equal to Sunday. There is no date associated with the data.

I want to merge the data into one field whereby the time will have a day of the week associated with it.

I have got the time ok with strptime:

```
time.strptime(fl['journey']['BeginTime'][row], "%H:%M:%S")
```

Which gives the format:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=23, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

The digit corresponding to the day of week is stored in the following variable:

```
fl['journey']['Day'][row]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date_string = '{0} {1}'.format(fl['journey']['Day'][row] - 1,
                               fl['journey']['BeginTime'][row])

dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%w %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: `%A` depends on the current locale, and if it's already a number, why not use `%w`.

Comment: @mata because I didn't see %w, obviously.  :) Thanks.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid pretty sure I got an edit in right before you posted that, but good catch

Comment: Perfect, thanks mayhewr, a nice elegant solution. For anyone trying this, just be sure to int the column if it isn't already i.e. (int(fl['journey']['Day'][row])-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
date_string = "%d %s" % (int(fl['journey']['Day'][row]) % 7 ,
                         fl['journey']['BeginTime'][row])

date = time.strptime(date_string, '%w %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime("6 13:45:12", "%w %H:%M:%S").timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=13, tm_min=45, tm_sec=12, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Remember in Python weekdays start with 0 = Sunday and go till 6